# CodeIgniter Model array not pushing as expected

Tags: php, codeigniter

My CodeIgniter model method grabs all of the "cases" with a specific subcategory. Then it's suppose to translate those into a new array with proper "get_case" results but it keeps returning the same array element. Every associated method I debug seems to be functioning properly on its own, but in this function I get the same result repeated.

here is the method/function I am having trouble with... This seems like it should be simple

```
function get_subcategories_cases($subcategory)
    {
    $this->db->order_by('sortorder','asc');
    $this->db->where('subcategoryid', $subcategory);
    $query = $this->db->get('cases');
    $query = $query->result();
    //
    $outputArray = array();
    foreach ($query as $item) {
    array_push($outputArray, $this->get_case($item->id));
    }
    return $outputArray;
    }
```

here is the get_case method

```
function get_case($id)
{
//print_r($id);
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get('cases');
$query = $query->row();
//
$this->id               = $query->id;
$this->sortoder         = $query->sortorder;
$this->surgeonid        = $query->surgeonid;
$this->subcategoryid    = $query->subcategoryid;
$this->age              = $query->age;
$this->gender           = $query->gender;
$this->typeofsurgery    = $query->typeofsurgery;
$this->isactive = $query->isactive;
$this->isfeatured       = $query->isfeatured;
$this->iswarning        = $query->iswarning;
$this->metatitle        = $query->metatitle;
$this->metadescription  = $query->metadescription;
$this->metakeywords     = $query->metakeywords;
$this->casedescription  = $query->casedescription;
$this->photos       = $this->insert_case_photos($query->photos);
//
return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are saving the results in `get_case()` to `$this`, you are saving them to the model (object) attributes, which have scope outside of the `get_case()` method, so it maybe something to do with that.

Try saving the query result to a local variable:

```
function get_case($id)
{
    //print_r($id);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get('cases');
    $case = $query->row();
    //
    $case->photos = $case->insert_case_photos($case->photos);
    //
    return $case;
}
```

Comment: That's great - glad it helped. If you're happy with the response would you mind marking it as the accepted answer please? It helps keep SO organised and in return we both get better reputation :)